# How can i change the color of a table row depending of the mysql result with php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

im trying to change the color of my table. It depends on if the data in that field is the same that in other table of mysql db. it changes the color but i know that is not ok. i think the problem is that the array is in a while loop.

this is my code:

```
<?php
$counter2 = 0;
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM prod_defectuoso WHERE ticket_id = '$ticket_id'"     );
$nr = mysql_num_rows( $result );
if(empty($nr))
{
echo("
<tr>
<td colspan='3'><center>No hay Pieza o Partes Cambiados</center></td>
</tr>
");
}

echo("
<div style=\"margin-bottom:-5px\">
<table width=\"50%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\0\ cellpadding=\2\ class=\"dtable\"     align=\"center\">
<tr>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>#</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Descripci&oacute;n (Cambio)</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Serie</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Diagnostico</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Comentario</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Usuario</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Nombre del Courier</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>N&deg;Remito</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Devuelto el:</center></th>
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Creado el:</center></th>");
if($thisuser->isAdmin()) {
echo("
<th width='10%' nowrap><center>Borrar</center></th>
</tr>
");
}
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
$counter2;
$desc = $row["desc"];
$serial = $row["serial"];
$state = $row["state"];
$comment = $row["comment"];
$user = $row["user"];
$nomcourier = $row["nomcourier"];
$nremito = $row["nremito"];
$fdevolucion = $row["fdevolucion"];
$created = $row["created"];
$counter2 = $counter2 + 1;

//Mostramos prod_cambio.serial que no tiene "match" de valores con skus.serial
$show = mysql_query("select prod_defectuoso.serial from prod_defectuoso left join skus on >prod_defectuoso.serial = skus.serial where skus.serial is null");
$showme= mysql_fetch_array($show);
$ser = array ($row["serial"]);
print_r($ser);
echo '<br>'.((array_key_exists($serial,$ser))? 'item found' : 'item not found');

echo("<tr>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$counter2</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$desc</td>");
$color="#df8f8f";
if (array_key_exists("251902",$ser)){
echo("
<td width='200' style=\"background-color:$color\">$serial</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$state</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$comment</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$user</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$nomcourier</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$nremito</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$fenvio</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$created</td>
");
}
else{
echo("
<td width='200' nowrap>$serial</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$state</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$comment</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$user</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$nomcourier</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$nremito</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$fdevolucion</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$created</td>
");
}
if($thisuser->isAdmin()) {
echo("
<td width='10%' nowrap><a href='piopa.php?pdefectuoso_id=$pdefectuoso_id&id=$ticket_id'' >onClick=' return confirm(\"Esta seguro que desea BORRAR el inventario?\");'>Borrar</a>
</td>
</tr>
");
}
}
echo ("</table>");
echo("
<div aling=\"center\">*Los datos en Rojo no aparecen la Base de Datos</div>
");
mysql_free_result( $result );
?>
```

Comment: maybe there isn't "251902" key?

Comment: for td you also can use <td bgcolor="#df8f8f">

Comment: try to set <td width='200' style="background-color: #df8f8f">$serial</td>  or just check your html source and you'l understand is you key in the array, or not. And why there is array_key_exists("251902",$ser) ? I think it should be array_key_exists($serial,$ser)

Comment: hi, there is "251902" key but it does not change the color. is the same if i change "251902" with $serial

Comment: check your html output, is there style=\"background-color: ? or not

Comment: i just change the td to<td width='200' bgcolor=\"#df8f8f\">$serial</td> but it doesnt work

this is my code right now:
    `if (array_key_exists($serial,$ser)){
    echo("
    <td width='200' bgcolor=\"#df8f8f\">$serial</td>`

Comment: if i change this:
    `if (array_key_exists($serial,$ser)){ 
    echo(" <td width='200' bgcolor=\"#df8f8f\">$serial</td>`
to this:
    `if ($ser[0] == $serial){
    echo("
    <td width='200' style=\"background-color:$color\">$serial</td>`
it change all the fields to red but its wrong.

Comment: right-click on your page in your browser and choose "view source" (or something like that). then find this td row and check if there this "bgcolor" exists

Comment: if you look at this part 
`echo '<br>'.((array_key_exists($serial,$ser))? 'item found' : 'item not found');`
it prints item not found in all array options but in the db i can see the "251902"

Comment: and what print_r($ser) is showing?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 123456 )
Array ( [0] => 123234 )
Array ( [0] => 123456 )
Array ( [0] => 251897 )
Array ( [0] => 251902 )

Comment: actually you check $row["serial"] in array($row["serial"]). Maybe you should check it exist in $showme["serial"] ???

Comment: when i change to $ser = array($showme["serial"]); it prints:
Array ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 123456 )

Comment: if i change it to:
`while ($showme= mysql_fetch_array($show)){
    $ser = array($showme["serial"]);
    print_r($ser);
    }`
it prints rray ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 123234 ) Array ( [0] => 123456 ) Array ( [0] => 251897 ) Array ( [0] => 251902 )
for every row cause its inside a while.

Comment: and show me all the serial rows in red but its not Ok
the select in mysql `(select prod_defectuoso.serial from prod_defectuoso left join skus on prod_defectuoso.serial = skus.serial where skus.serial is null)` shows: 
serial:
123456
123234
123456
251897
251902

Comment: it change the color of all serail rows but its supposed to change only the "123456" "123234" "123456"
thats what my select shows i dont know whats wrong.

Comment: sorry in the sql select shows only 123456 123234 123456 thats why in my php im supposed to see only those rows in red and not all

Comment: no one can help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution to my question.
here it is:

```
//Mostramos prod_cambio.serial que no tiene "match" de valores con skus.serial
$show = mysql_query("select prod_defectuoso.serial from prod_defectuoso left join skus on prod_defectuoso.serial = skus.serial where skus.serial is null");
//$shows = array();
//$ser = array($shows["serial"]);
while ($showme= mysql_fetch_assoc($show)){
$shows[] = $showme['serial'];
$mem2 = $row['serial'];
//print_r($showme);
}
echo("<tr>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$counter2</td>
<td width='10%' nowrap>$desc</td>");
$color="#df8f8f";
//if ($showme = $serial){
if (in_array($mem2, $shows)) {    
echo("
<td width='200' style=\"background-color:$color\">$serial</td>
```